# Crear div dinamicamente para ver el contenido de una frase

Tags: javascript, web, div

Estoy creando un programa que usa `Javascript` y `Hmtl`.

Se trata de escribir una frase en un `input` que solo puede funcionar una vez. Desde ahí se separa con `split` con el caracter espacio, tiene un longitud de 8 palabras la frase y a cada letra se crea una imagen con una carta y aparecen en el `html`.

Por otro lado se vuelve a separar la frase y se crea una letra que debe estar detrás de la carta por decirlo de alguna manera y aparecer al mover el ratón.

El problema está en la función iniciar que hace como una selección de las dos funciones con el evento onmouseover al pasar el ratón por encima de cada imagen creada por cada letra de la frase se debe descrubrir la letra que corresponde a cada posición de la frase y luego ocultarse automáticamente, pienso que iba bien encaminado pero no tengo tantas nociones de Js porfavor confío en que como he visto otras veces me pueden ayudar en este foro, muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo para ti, DjCrazy, gracias por contestarme

Me vale cualquier consejo, gracias!

```js
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar() {

  var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');

  currentDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', div, false);
  src.addEventListener('mouseout', imagen, false);
}

function imagen() {
  var contenido = document.getElementById('palabra').value.toUpperCase();
  let arr = contenido.split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "R.jpg";
    var src = document.getElementById("bloque0" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(img, src);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[1].length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "R.jpg";
    var src = document.getElementById("bloque1" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(img, src);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[2].length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "R.jpg";
    var src = document.getElementById("bloque2" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(img, src);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[3].length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "R.jpg";
    var src = document.getElementById("bloque3" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(img, src);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[4].length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "R.jpg";
    var src = document.getElementById("bloque4" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(img, src);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[5].length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "R.jpg";
    var src = document.getElementById("bloque5" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(img, src);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[6].length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "R.jpg";
    var src = document.getElementById("bloque6" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(img, src);
  }

}

function div() {
  var contenido = document.getElementById('palabra').value.toUpperCase();
  let arr = contenido.split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(arr[0][i]);
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("bloque0" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[1].length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(arr[1][i]);
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("bloque1" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[2].length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(arr[2][i]);
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("bloque2" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
    console.log(arr[2]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[3].length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(arr[3][i]);
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("bloque3" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
    console.log(arr[3]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[4].length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(arr[4][i]);
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("bloque4" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
    console.log(arr[4]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[5].length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(arr[5][i]);
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("bloque5" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
    console.log(arr[5]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[6].length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(arr[6][i]);
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("bloque6" + i);
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
    console.log(arr[6]);
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: blue;
}

input {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
}

div div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.contenedor-columna {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Wordle</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    <input id="palabra" type="password" placeholder="Introduce palabra...">
    <a href="#" class="boton" id="boton-comprobar" onclick="imagen()">Comprobar</a>
  </form>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div id="bloque00" mouseover="div()" mouseout="imagen()" style="border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque01" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque02" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque03" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque04" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque05" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque06" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque07" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="bloque10" onclick="div()" style="border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque11" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque12" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque13" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque14" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque15" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque16" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque17" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="bloque20" onclick="div()" style="border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque21" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque22" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque23" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque24" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque25" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque26" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque27" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="bloque30" onclick="div()" style="border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque31" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque32" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque33" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque34" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque35" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque36" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque37" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="bloque40" onclick="div()" style="border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque41" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque42" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque43" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque44" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque45" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque46" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque47" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="bloque50" onclick="div()" style="border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque51" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque52" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque53" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque54" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque55" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque56" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div id="bloque57" style="display: none">
  </div>

  <script src="js/palabra.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu problema específico? Qué te falta? Qué no te funciona. Te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas el funcionamiento de la comunidad y así puedas [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/548687/edit) tu pregunta de acuerdo a las normas.

Comment: El problema está en la función iniciar que hace como una selección de las dos funciones con el evento onmouseover al pasar el ratón por encima de cada imagen creada por cada letra de la frase se debe descrubrir la letra que corresponde a cada posición de la frase y luego ocultarse automáticamente, pienso que iba bien encaminado pero no tengo tantas nociones de Js porfavor confío en que como he visto otras veces me pueden ayudar en este foro, muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo para ti, DjCrazy, gracias por contestarme